# A quiz question in real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am trying to solve this quiz questions of senior batch in Real Analysis:

[image]

For disproving (A) (B) option $f(x) =x^{6}$ was sufficient.

But I am unable to think how to prove/ disprove (C) , (D) the problem arising due to function being given bounded in (C) and infinitely differentiability asked in (D).

Comment: Never post unsearchable pictures of text.  Instead typeset using *MathJax*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To rule out (D) start with a nonnegative continuous function that's not differentiable - perhaps $g(x) = |x|$. Then construct $f$ by integrating twice, so that $g$ is its second derivative. Then the integral of $f$ will be only three times differentiable.

Answer (score 2):

Hint for (C): if $f'' \ge 0$ and $f'(x) > 0$, then $f'(t) \ge f'(x)$ for all $t \ge x$, so $f(t) \ge f(x) + (t-x) f'(x)$ for $t \ge x$.  Similarly in the opposite direction if $f'(x) < 0$.

Comment: In other words, $f'' \geq 0$ implies that $f$ is convex. And a convex bounded function is constant.

Comment: @Robert Israel how does f'(t) $\geq$ f'(x) implies f(t) $\geq$f(x) $+( t-x) f'(x)  ? Can you please tell exact reasoning for this step?

Comment: For $t \ge x$, $$f(t) - f(x) = \int_x^t f'(s)\; ds \ge \int_x^t f'(x)\; ds = (t-x) f'(x)$$

Comment: @Avenger Without relying on integrals: Clearly $t = x$ is trivial, so assume $t > x$. We can then apply the mean value theorem on $f : [x,t] \to \mathbb{R}$, ie, we find a $x<t_0<t$ such that $$f(t) - f(x) = f'(t_0) (t-x).$$ And because $t_0 > x$ we get $$f(t) - f(x) = f'(t_0) (t-x) \ge f'(x) (t-x).$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Show that if $f$ has nonzero gradient at any point, then it cannot be bounded.