# Twice differentiable but not infinitely differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, functions, examples-counterexamples

I want an example of a function satisfying:

(1) $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ twice continuously differentiable

(2) $f''(x)$ $\ge 0$ for every x$\in \mathbb R$

(3)$\int\limits_0^x{f(t)dt}$ is NOT infinitely differentiable with respect to x.

I find it very difficult to get a function satisfying conditions 2 and 3. If I try $e^t$ it violates 3. If I try a function involving $t^5$sin(1/t), it violates condition 2. Please help me with a correct example. Thank you.

Comment: Something like $x^2|x|$ should do the work

Comment: Great. It works. It did not strike me.

Comment: BTW, what is the purpose of the second condition?

Comment: @Dmitry It is easy if condition 2 is not there. We can take f(x)= x^3 ((sin (1/x))

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A quiz question in real analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3748738/a-quiz-question-in-real-analysis)

Comment: @EthanBolker yes thank you. Solution is available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do it: Define $g(s) = 1-s^2, |s|\le 1,$ $g=0$ elsewhere. Set

$$f(x) = \int_0^x\int_0^t g(s)\,ds\,dt.$$

Note $f''(x) = g(x),$ which is not differentiable at $\pm 1.$

Comment: Awesome example. This example gives a technique of finding functions not satisfying a given property using double integrals. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

How can $$G(t)=\int_0^t[1-s^2] ds = t(1-\frac13t^2)$$ be differentiable at both $1$ and $-1$ and yield $g(s)$? As a hobbyist, I have to work it out explicitly.
Since $G(-1)=-\frac23$ and $G(1)=\frac23$, we define
$$G(t)=\begin{cases}
t(1-\frac13t^2), &|t|\le 1,\\
-\frac23, &t<1,\\
\frac23, &t>1
\end{cases}$$
Piecewise differentiation yields $g(t)=g(s)$.
Then differentiating $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{x^2}{12}(6-{x^2}), &|x|\le 1,\\
-\frac23x, &x<1,\\
\frac23x, &x>1
\end{cases}$$
yields $G(x)=G(t)$. Thanks!